# Record and Mix Audio Real-Time in Android

Tags: android, audio, real-time, record, soundpool

Is it possible to record audio from an microphone on an Android device and then combine it with whatever the phone is currently playing at real-time? This is the premise of my app, so before I can start I need to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your question, you would like to mix your voice with music.
The problem is that during the music playing you will register the voice and also the music, so the quality of it will be very bad.

If you intend to speak and then mix with some music, I confirm to you that you can have this result only using some C project like SOX.

Me and my team are preparing an app for Facebook that will be published by end of next week (March 10th 2012), and once it will be published I will inform to you and you will take some idea from it.....

Comment: My app is a safety one, it is meant to be used like if you are listening to music through earbuds, but want to hear outside noise in real-time for safety. It is going to be for runners or bike riders.